# Java time (Minutes:Seconds:Miliseconds)

Tags: java

Hey i have any idea how i can format long time to
Minutes:Seconds:Miliseconds for example 01:57:934
i can use `String.format(0#.0#.###)` but what transform this long to time ;?

Comment: When you deal with dates and times, I would recommend you to use the java Date class, or even better, the even superior time library yodatime: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use SimpleDateFormat assuming you have less than one hour.

```
String text = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SSS").format(new Date(time));
```

or you can use plain math.

```
String text = String.format("%02d:%02d:%03d", time/60000, time/1000%60, time/1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.5 there is the java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit class, use it like this:

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
);
```

For Java versions below 1.5 or for systems that do not fully support the TimeUnit class (such as Android before API version 9), the following equations can be used:

```
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```

Comment: +1, although I don't believe it is related to the Android API, because this is a java class

Comment: It isn't related to Android API at all

Comment: TimeUnit.MINUTES and TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes() do only exist since Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

long timeDiff =  (d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());

```
    String diff=String.format("%d year(s) %d day(s) %d hour(s) %d min(s) %d sec(s)",(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timeDiff)/365),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timeDiff)%365,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff)
            - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
            .toDays(timeDiff)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff)
            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
            .toHours(timeDiff)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeDiff)
            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
            .toMinutes(timeDiff)));
    System.out.println(diff);
```

Specify correct date here in d1 & d2.Then you will get right answer of difference